# Bent Arrow Symbol

Tags: symbols, arrows

[image]

Could you help me with search of such arrow symbol in latex, please?

I know that there is `\hookrightarrow`. But it's not what I want to use in my article.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: You can try `\usepackage{mathabx} \drsh` or `\usepackage{fdsymbol} \Rdsh`... both of which was obtained by looking at the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive). Possible duplicate: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)

Comment: @Werner Thank you, `\drsh` is very close!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TikZ answer; you could personalize the appeareance passing TikZ style commands in the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\myarrow}[1][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]%
    \draw (0,0.7ex) -- (0,0) -- (0.75em,0);
    \draw (0.55em,0.2em) -- (0.75em,0) -- (0.55em,-0.2em);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\myarrow

\myarrow[scale=5]

\myarrow[draw=red]

\end{document}
```

[image: Arrows drawn in TikZ]